# Do async methods throw exceptions on call or on await?

Tags: c#, async-await

When I call an async method and get a task back, will that immediately throw or will it wait until I await the task?

In other words, will this code work? Or will I have to wrap the method call in the try-block as well?

```
Task task = ThisMethodWillThrow();

try
{
    await task;
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("oops");
}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Both are possible. If the method is actually `async` (i.e. uses the C# `async` keyword in the declaration), then the C# compiler wraps it up in such a way that it will always reliably throw on the `await`, but it is important to note that this is **not** the only way to write a method that can be `await`-ed, so: if you don't control the method being called (`ThisMethodWillThrow`) and can't rely on knowledge of the implementation, it would be better for the `try` to include the initial invoke, as well as the `await`.

As an example of a method that will throw immediately rather than in the `await`:

```
Task ThisMethodWillThrow() { // note that this is **not** "async", but is awaitable
    if (thingsAreBad) throw new SomeException();
    return SomeInnerMethod();
}
async Task SomeInnerMethod() { ... }
```

It *might* be tempting to think "well, just make all awaitable methods `async`, to avoid this" - like:

```
async Task ThisMethodWillThrowToo() { // note that this is "async"
    if (thingsAreBad) throw new SomeException();
    await SomeInnerMethod();
}
```

However: there are scenarios where the async machinery is a very measurable performance overhead in the "often sync, sometimes async" case - and so a common optimization in performance critical awaitable code (IO/network code, for example) is to **actively avoid** the `async` machinery unless we know that we're actually falling into the asynchronous path.

Comment: So this means, it is possible that, the task throws right before .ContinueWith(..., TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted)?

Comment: @SakamotoPoteko yes; `ContinueWith` will only be called if the thing that *returns* the task completes and returns a task - this itself is not guaranteed (although a method decorated with `async` will always do so). Note: you *really shouldn't be using* `ContinueWith` any more... that is the old-old-old API; the preferred way of working with tasks now really is: `await`. The implementation is optimized with that intent.