# Are sync exceptions possible in HttpClient?

Tags: c#, dotnet-httpclient

Right now, I'm not talking about `ArgumentNullException` or `InvalidOperationException`, but more or less only about `HttpRequestException`.

```
var responseAsync = httpClient.SendAsync(something);
try
{
    var response = await responseAsync;
}
catch(Exception)
{
}
```

Will this code ever throw any exceptions, or can we safely assume that all the possible exceptions can only happen during the `await`?

Comment: Do you have a specific reason for not just protecting both the `SendAsync` and the `await` by the same `try`/`catch`? I don't think it's specifically documented which exceptions can/cannot be thrown synchronously.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Do async methods throw exceptions on call or on await?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53445650/do-async-methods-throw-exceptions-on-call-or-on-await)

Comment: @janw I know that both are possible, otherwise I wouldn't even ask

Comment: Shown code wouldn't compile. If you want to `throw` on failed response, you may use ` `HttpResponseMessage.EnsureSuccessStatusCode()` method.

Comment: First of all, it will compile, why wouldn't it. Second of all, what unsuccessful status code has to do with httpClient sync exceptions? Not only ```HttpResponseMessage``` is created after the ```Task```, it actually creates on task's completion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*"but more or less only about HttpRequestException"*

MSDN:

The [doco](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient.sendasync?view=netcore-3.1) makes it quite clear:

> HttpRequestException
> The request failed due to an underlying issue such as **network connectivity, DNS failure, server certificate validation** or **timeout**.

So the answer would be *"yes"* if say your cat pulled out the network lead for example.

> Will this code ever throw any exceptions,

Yes.

> or can we safely assume that all the possible exceptions can only happen during the await?

It can occur on the following line too because by the time `SendAsync` returns (not to be confused with when the `Task` is complete), the `Task` has already been created and there is a tiny chance of it throwing before you get to the next line.

```
var responseAsync = httpClient.SendAsync(something);
```

EDIT: (from my comment below)
Also, for all we know, `SendAsync` might perform some "initial check" prior to the `Task` being created.  In which case you'll need a `try/catch` on the above.

Comment: So can you list (at least roughly) the situations when the sync exceptions are possible? I understood about general connectivity. That's logical, if there are no net interfaces available then no need to await. But even the DNS part should already be async, is it not?

Comment: @Morse It's entirely possible that an exeption can be thrown before the actual `Task` is created.  You'll again need to wrap those in a `try/catch`.  I'm not quite sure why you are not wanting to place `httpClient.SendAsync` in a single `try/catch`.